# Round Robin implementation in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I tried to implement round robin in java please check and help me to 
improve it Thanks:

```
package trial.java;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Roundrobin1 {
//common interval for all process.
static int commonInt=3;
//to store a list of queued process
Map<String, Integer> waitingMAp=new LinkedHashMap<>();
List<Integer>waitingTimeList=new ArrayList<>();
//to Store elapsed time.
int timepassed=0;

public  void mainL(){
    //input process name and time in order.
    waitingMAp.put("p0", 3);
    waitingMAp.put("p1", 3);
    waitingMAp.put("p2", 3);
    waitingMAp.put("p3", 9);
    //first time getting the list of process.
    List<String>process=new ArrayList<>();
    //it will call recursively till no process is waiting.
    while(!waitingMAp.isEmpty()){
        process.addAll(this.getRoundRobin(waitingMAp));
    }
    System.out.print(process);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(waitingTimeList);
}

    public List<String> getRoundRobin(Map<String, Integer> 
    processMap){
    Map<String, Integer> Local=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Local.putAll(processMap);
    waitingMAp.clear();
    List <String>curr=new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry :Local.entrySet()){
        curr.add(entry.getKey());

   waitingTimeList.add(entry.getValue()>3?timepassed=timepassed+3:     (timepassed=timepassed+entry.getValue()));

        if(entry.getValue()>commonInt){
            waitingMAp.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()-commonInt);
        }
        }

    return curr;

    }
    public static void main(String[] a){
    new Roundrobin1().mainL();

    }



}
```

it will return below result:
first row is order and second row is time elapsed.
[p0, p1, p2, p3, p3, p3]
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]

I would like to add couple of questions here

1. Do I need to take priorities of  the process as well in the input.If yes how it going to solve starvation problem.
2. How to scale up this algorithm for multiprocessor or multi-core systems

Answer (score 1):

**Naming**

Your variables, class and methods aren't very well named.

The class `Roundrobin1` should be [Pascal case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase). It's also discouraged from using numbers in class names. If you are thinking of doing implementations of Round Robin, perhaps `DefaultRoundRobin` would be okay. If not, just `RoundRobin` is fine.

You have a local variable named `Local`. Variables should always be camel case to distinguish them from classes.

You also have a few inconsistencies such as `timepassed`, which should be `timePassed`, and `waitingMAp` which should be `waitingMap`.

It's not clear what the method `mainL` is supposed to do. Give it a more specific name.

**Fields**

Fields should be declared with the lowest access possible. Your fields can be `private` as they are not required outside of the class. Fields should be declared as `final` if you do not expect them to change.

**Whitespace**

Consider using it more liberally, especially between operators.

```
entry.getValue() > commonInt
```

is easier to read than

```
entry.getValue()>commonInt
```

**Compound Statements**

Specifically this line:

```
waitingTimeList.add(entry.getValue()>3?timepassed=timepassed+3:     (timepassed=timepassed+entry.getValue()));
```

has *way too much* going on. You could refactor it to:

```
timepassed += (entry.getValue() > 3) ? 3 : entry.getValue();
waitingTimeList.add(timepassed);
```

which is much more readable.

**Magic Numbers**

You have a few seemingly random 3s and 9s. Consider using constants (`static final` fields) with appropriate names.

Comment: thanks for the comments ..i was in a hurry then i will apply these changes.